# How do i change player position in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im new to c# and i don't know much but i wanna know how to change the position of players and all i have is this line of code: `transform.position = 0.067, 1.52, -0.37;` It throws an error at me.

Comment: Hi, although this seems answered, it would help if you show us the error ;-)

Comment: Id imagine the error points to the first comment and, for want of looking up it will say some form of syntax error at the comma.. because it just doesnt work that way.  One thing most people dont do is read the unity docs which contain many examples and these will help you above all else learn unity as most of them contain examples and also helps you establish what other things are available in that class.. as sometimes there is a better way.. For example, setting a position teleports your character, rather than moves it there, this can cause issues in the long run if thats not what you want

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1R6qcSo Here i have a screenshot of the code.

Comment: right, there is no where in the world where `transform.position = 0.067, 1.52, -0.37;` is valid c# code, and there in is your issue, as predicted it looks at the comma and goes WTF are you expecting me to do with this, this does not make sense.. Its like you asking me how much is a stamp and me saying red.

Comment: use Vector3 for this

Answer (score 6):

Transform.position also takes **vector3** object `new vector3(x,y,z)`

Now, you can set all cordinates value in `vector3` object & pass it to `transform.position`.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(0.067f,1.52f,-0.37f);
```

**Edit:**
As you have error about (converting `int` to `float`). So wherever you have to write `float` in unity add keyword `f` (single small f) after the value.

```
int a = 4        //int doesn't require `f`
float a = 4.002f //decimal require f, else throw error
```

Comment: Well i tried it and it doesn't. It can't convert dobule to float.

Comment: you need to put "f" after each number so 0.067f, 1.52f, -0.37f

Answer (score -3):

Try re-positioning using an external reference.

```
public Transform Target;

void Start()
{
transform.postition = target.position;
}
```

Just create a gameobject where you want your object to be repositioned and pass that gameobject to your script and press play > it will reposition you object to your target position.